# Integration test redux-observable that makes multiple ajax requests with debounce

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a redux-observable epic that polls an endpoint, getting progress updates until the progress is 100%. The polling interval is acheived using debounceTime like so:

```
function myEpic(action$, store, dependencies) {
  return action$.ofType('PROCESSING')
    .do(action => console.log(`RECEIVED ACTION: ${JSON.stringify(action)}`))
    .debounceTime(1000, dependencies.scheduler)
    .mergeMap(action => (
      dependencies.ajax({ url: action.checkUrl })
        .map((resp) => {
          if (parseInt(resp.progress, 10) === 100) {
            return { type: 'SUCCESS' };
          }
          return { checkUrl: resp.check_url, progress: resp.progress, type: 'PROCESSING' };
        })));
}
```

This works fine but I'd like to write an integration test that tests the state of the store when progress is at 25%, then at 50%, then at 100%.

In my integration tests I can set `dependencies.scheduler` to be `new VirtualTimeScheduler()`.

This is how I'm trying to do it at the moment (using jest):

```
  describe('my integration test', () => {

    const scheduler = new VirtualTimeScheduler();

    beforeEach(() => {

      // Fake ajax responses
      const ajax = (request) => {

        console.log(`FAKING REQUEST FOR URL: ${request.url}`);

        if (request.url === '/check_url_1') {
          return Observable.of({ progress: 25, check_url: '/check_url_2' });
        } else if (request.url === '/check_url_2') {
          return Observable.of({ progress: 50, check_url: '/check_url_3' });
        } else if (request.url === '/check_url_3') {
          return Observable.of({ progress: 100 });
        }
        return null;
      };
      store = configureStore(defaultState, { ajax, scheduler });
    });

    it('should update the store properly after each call', () => {
      store.dispatch({ checkUrl: '/check_url_1', progress: 0, type: 'PROCESSING' });

      scheduler.flush();
      console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 25');

      scheduler.flush();
      console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 50');

      scheduler.flush();
      console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 100');
    });
  });
```

My expected output would be:

```
RECEIVED ACTION: {"checkUrl":"/check_url_1","progress":0,"type":"PROCESSING"}
FAKING REQUEST FOR URL: /check_url_1
CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 25
RECEIVED ACTION: {"checkUrl":"/check_url_2","progress":25,"type":"PROCESSING"}
FAKING REQUEST FOR URL: /check_url_2
CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 50
RECEIVED ACTION: {"checkUrl":"/check_url_3","progress":50,"type":"PROCESSING"}
# CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 100
```

But instead the output I get is

```
RECEIVED ACTION: {"checkUrl":"/check_url_1","progress":0,"type":"PROCESSING","errors":null}
FAKING REQUEST FOR URL: /check_url_1
RECEIVED ACTION: {"checkUrl":"/check_url_2","progress":25,"type":"PROCESSING","errors":null}
CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 25%
CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 50%
CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 100%
```

At which time the test finishes. I'm configuring the store so that I can mock ajax requests and the scheduler used for debounceTime like as recommended [here](https://github.com/shakyShane/egghead-redux-obs/blob/13/src/configureStore.js)

So my question is how can I test the state of my store after each of the three ajax requests?

Comment: Any particular reason an integration test vs a unit testing your epics separate from your reducers; unit testing wouldn't require redux to be involved at all. You would then call your epic directly https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html

Comment: You might have a reason btw, that was a question not a statement :)

Comment: @jayphelps I wanted to have a higher level test that tested more of the "whole system" working together. If it's not possible I guess I could just stick with unit tests, but hopefully there's some way to do it, there may come a stage where we write automated click tests too with enzyme too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I played around with your code and am fairly confident you just found a bug in the `debounceTime` operator, which causes the apparent swallowing the scheduled debounce. The bad news is that even if that bug is fixed, you're code still wouldn't do what you're looking for order wise.

Bear with me as shit is about to get real:

- Epic receives action PROCESSING and schedules debounce, yielding execution to your test
- Your test calls `scheduler.flush()` and the VirtualScheduler executes the scheduled debounce work, which will pass along the original PROCESSING action to the `mergeMap`
- Fake ajax is made, which *synchronously* emits a response
- Response is mapped to the second PROCESSING action
- Your epic emits that second action synchronously
- The second action is recursively received by your epic and given to the debounce
- The debounceTime operator now schedules that second action on the VirtualScheduler but the debounceTime operator **is in the middle of executing the previously scheduled work still** from the first action.
- The call stack unwinds a bunch up until it reaches inside the previously scheduled debounce work from the first action that had just next()'d the first action. The **rxjs code for `debounceTime` then sets [`this.lastValue = null` and `this.hasValue = false`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/debounceTime.ts#L100-L102) This is the rxjs bug, it needs to be done before nexting into the destination**
- The stack unwinds some more to the running flush() method of the VirtualScheduler, [which now dequeues the second scheduled debounced action](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.ts#L27) because it was added the scheduled work array synchronously, before this the flushing finished. Remember, we've only called `scheduler.flush()` ONCE so far, which is the function we're in back in at this point.
- The second scheduled debounce work is run, but `this.hasValue === false` because the first scheduled one set it, so the debounceTime operator does not emit anything.
- Stack unwinds to our first `scheduler.flush()`
- We `console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 25')`
- All the other `scheduler.flush()` calls do nothing as there's nothing scheduled.

---

This is technically a bug, but it's not surprising that no one has run into it since running debounce synchronously without any delay defeats the point of it, *except when you're testing, of course*. [This ticket is basically the same thing](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2748) and OJ says RxJS doesn't make reentrancy guarantees, but I that might be up for debate in this case. [I've filed a PR with the fix to discuss](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3218)

Remember, this bug wouldn't have solved your underlying question about the ordering, but would have prevented the actions from being swallowed.

Off the top of my head I'm not sure how you would do what you'd like to do specifically if you want to maintain 100% synchronous behavior (VirtualScheduler). You'd need some way of yielding to your test in between debounces. For me when and if I write integration tests I mock out very little, if anything. e.g. let the debounces actually debounce either naturally or by mocking out setTimeout to advance them quicker but **still keeping them async** which will yield back to your test allowing you to check the state, but making your test also async.

---

For anyone wanting to reproduce, [here's the StackBlitz code I used](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-byidhv?file=configureStore.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! I'll have a look into re-writing the tests asynchronously, mocking setTimeout

Comment: Hey @JamesPlayer did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to re-write the test asynchronously. Also note-worthy is that I had to mock the ajax requests by returning an `Observable.fromPromise` rather than just a regular `Observable.of`, otherwise they would still get swallowed up by the debounce. Something along these lines (using jest):

```
describe('my integration test', () => {

  const scheduler = new VirtualTimeScheduler();

  beforeEach(() => {

    // Fake ajax responses
    const ajax = request => (
      Observable.fromPromise(new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (request.url === '/check_url_1') {
          resolve({ response: { progress: 25, check_url: '/check_url_2' } });
        } else if (request.url === '/check_url_2') {
          resolve({ response: { progress: 50, check_url: '/check_url_3' } });
        } else {
          resolve({ response: { progress: 100 } });
        }
      }))
    );

    store = configureStore(defaultState, { ajax, timerInterval: 1 });
  });

  it('should update the store properly after each call', (done) => {

    let i = 0;
    store.subscribe(() => {
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 0');
          break;
        case 1:
          console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 25');
          break;
        case 2:
          console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 50');
          break;
        case 3:
          console.log('CHECK CORRECT STATE FOR PROGRESS 100');
          done();
          break;
        default:
      }
      i += 1;
    });

    store.dispatch({ checkUrl: '/check_url_1', progress: 0, type: 'PROCESSING' });
  });
});
```

I also set the timer interval to 1 by passing it as a dependency. In my epic I set it like this: `.debounceTime(dependencies.timerInterval || 1000)`